# Create parameter for multidimensional evaluation in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a functional evaluation which has many parameters, and I want to vectorize the evaluation. Something like this:

```
  I = 100
  J = 34
  K = 6
  i, j, k = array(range(I)), array(range(J)), array(range(K))
  i, j, k = meshgrid(i, j, k)

  f = myfun(i, j, k)
```

This is excellent, however, now I also have a parameter that I want to send to myfun that I generate with some other function and that is invariant over some of the indices above, thus:

```
  p = my_param_gen()
```

and let's say

```
  p.shape()
```

will output

```
  (100, 6)
```

This would correspond to p being invariant over the index J. Now, I would like to expand the shape of p to be

```
  (100, 34, 6)
```

in a meshgrid-kind of fashion so that the new dimension is filled constant with the old dimensions. How do I do this the best? The approach should work also with adding many new dimensions. I have seen numpy.expand_dims, but it does not do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
In [116]: i.shape
Out[116]: (34, 100, 6)
```

If `p.shape` is (100,6), then `p` will broadcast with `i,j,k` without further change.  That is `p[None,:,:]` expansion is automatic.

If you'd used `i, j, k = np.meshgrid(i, j, k, indexing='ij')`,

```
In [121]: i.shape
Out[121]: (100, 34, 6)
```

And `p[:,None,:]` would be needed for broadcasting (equilvalently `np.expand_dims(p,1)`)